# Appending JSON array to select

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I am trying to append this JSON array to a select box

```
{
  "10":"Branche",
  "2":"Marketing & Comunicatie",
  "8":"Test Branche 1",
  "9":"Test Branche 2",
  "6":"Test Branche 3",
  "7":"Test Branche 4",
  "1":"Webdevelopment & design"
}
```

But it doesn't work I encoded it from a PHP array. This is how I am trying to loop through it.

```
this.addOption = function(name, table, value){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: {action:'add', table:table, value:value},
        url: "index.php",
    })
    .done(function( obj ) {
        $("#"+name+"-select").empty()
        console.log(name);
        $.each(obj, function( key, value ) {
            $("#"+name+"-select").append('<option value='+key+'>'+value+'</option>');
        });
    });
}
```

Where obj is the JSON array.

It is giving me this error:

[image]

Comment: How does your JSON come to `obj`? Maybe it needs to be parsed again.

Comment: Seems fine to me: http://jsfiddle.net/2nas43ae/

Comment: Oh thats weird.. must be somewhere else in my code then I guess.. I updated my answer to the whole AJAX request.

Comment: did you tried with $.each(obj.data, functio...

Comment: @SinanSamet You should show a screenshot of the data being returned from PHP (via dev tools). More than likely it's invalid/not what you're expecting

Comment: is the data looks fine in console ?

Comment: Yes in the console everything looks fine. @RGraham I added a picture of the error I get in the console

Comment: Try explicitly setting `dataType: 'json'` in your `$.ajax()` options?

Comment: Thank you Anthony that worked! Sorry for my stupid mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that your PHP is outputting the JSON with a content type of `text/html` and because you haven't told jQuery you're expecting JSON, it won't parse the response, and in the end you're trying to call `$.each` on a string.

Add a dataType to tell jQuery to explicitly parse the response as JSON:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: {action:'add', table:table, value:value},
    url: "index.php",
    dataType: 'json'
})
```

Alternatively, set the correct content type in your PHP:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use following way:

```
 for(k in obj) {
    $("#branch-select").append('<option value='+k+'>'+obj[k]+'</option>');
 }
```

Comment: Indeed they can. But that's not the question :)